# AdMob ID inst loading ads, while test ID works

Tags: java, admob

I set up an AdMob account over 24 hours ago and my ID won't work, but the Test ID works for me.

```
mInterstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(context);
mInterstitialAd.setAdUnitId("ca-app-pub-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/yyyyyyyyyy");
mInterstitialAd.loadAd(request);

If(AmountOfOvers = 5){
      mInterstitialAd.show();
}
```

Again the code above works with the test ID but not with my ID, and I waited over 24 hours. So did I just do something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Did you register the listeners for the Admob interstitial?

The onAdFailedToLoad(int) will show you in detail why no ad gets loaded.

```
mInterstitialAd.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
    @Override
    public void onAdFailedToLoad(int errorCode) {
        Log.d(onAdFailedToLoad, "This is why: "+errorCode);
    }
```

https://developers.google.com/admob/android/interstitial

The error codes can be of this nature:

- **ERROR_CODE_INTERNAL_ERROR** (int 0) - Something happened internally; for instance, an invalid response was received from the ad server.
- **ERROR_CODE_INVALID_REQUEST** (int 1) - The ad request was invalid; for instance, the ad unit ID was incorrect.
- **ERROR_CODE_NETWORK_ERROR** (int 2) - The ad request was unsuccessful due to network connectivity.
- **ERROR_CODE_NO_FILL** (int 3) - The ad request was successful, but no ad was returned due to lack of ad inventory.